# Trying to get row data alert. Why am I getting multiple alerts on click?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am at early stages of learning js and jquery. I am stuck in a problem I dont understand.
I have a HTML form where I am collecting user inputs. When submit button is clicked the user input is saved as a new row to a table (Lets call it "myTable"). I got that part done. But now I want to get the row data when I click on a row in myTable. I kind of have that too. I do get the data when clicking on the row, Except when I click on the row I get the same data in alert multiple times. The first time I click on the row I get one alert, the second time two... and so on. Please point out my error.Here is my html:

```
<div>label>First Name: </label>
<input id="firstname" type="text" name="first name"/>

<br>
<label>Last Name: </label>
<input id="lastname" type="text" name="last name"/>

<input type ="button" value = "Submit" onclick ="addRow()" >
</div>

<table id="myTable" border=1 onclick="load_row()">
        <tr >
            <td>
            First Name
            </td>
            <td>
            Last Name
            </td>
        </tr>
</table>
```

And here is my javascript:
This function adds the user input as new row to the table:

```
var addRow = function(){
var firstname = document.getElementById("firstname").value;
var lastname = document.getElementById("lastname").value;


$("#myTable tr:last").after("<tr><td>" + firstname + "</td><td>" + lastname + "</td></tr>" );   
};
```

And this function is alerting with the details of the row I click on. This is where I guess I'm doing something wrong:

```
var load_row = function(){
var rows = $("#myTable tr");

rows.click(function() {
    var data = new Array();
    var cells = $(this).find("td");
    cells.each(function(i, cell) {
        data.push($(cell).text());
    });
    alert(data);
});

};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like you are adding a new click event to every row each time the user clicks. So, simply unbind the click event before you add a new one.

```
rows.unbind("click").click(function() {
  var data = new Array();
  var cells = $(this).find("td");
  cells.each(function(i, cell) {
    data.push($(cell).text());
  });
  alert(data);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

It's called bubbling, as soon as you click the TR, you also fire the event click of the TABLE you bound. So you're not just calling addRow, but also load_row, which again binds the .click event on each TR again.

Remove the onclick on the table element and add in a "script" tag somewhere in your "head" tag like

```
$(document).ready(function() { load_row() });
```

or add/change in between

```
row.click => rows.unbind('click').click
```

Comment: Didnt know anything about Bubbling till now. Thank you for this piece of info.

Answer (score 1):

It happens cause every time you call `load_raw` you bind +1 click event to every row.
So it's better to use jquery `on` binding and remove `click` binding from load_row function.

```
$('#myTable').on('click', 'tr', load_row())
```

Answer (score 0):

I cleaned up your code to remove the inline JavaScript calls, used more jQuery (`$("#firstname").val();` vs `document.getElementById("firstname").value`) and used the `.on()` function to properly bind the new rows added to the table.

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/zdy5E/)**.

**jQuery**

```
$('input[value="Submit"]').click(function() {
    var firstname = $("#firstname").val();
    var lastname = $("#lastname").val();
    $("#myTable tr:last").after("<tr><td>" + firstname + "</td><td>" + lastname + "</td></tr>");
});
$("#myTable").on('click', 'tr', function() {
    var data = new Array();
    var cells = $(this).find("td");
    cells.each(function(i, cell) {
        data.push($(cell).text());
    });
    alert(data);
});​
```

**HTML**

```
<div><label>First Name: </label>
<input id="firstname" type="text" name="first name"/>

<br>
<label>Last Name: </label>
<input id="lastname" type="text" name="last name"/>

<input type ="button" value="Submit" >
</div>

<table id="myTable" border=1>
        <tr >
            <td>
            First Name
            </td>
            <td>
            Last Name
            </td>
        </tr>
</table>​
```